# Bot Framework Composer - Publish profile

Tags: access-token, azure-bot-service, azure-function-app, bot-framework-composer

I'm using the Bot Framework Composer to create a bot and now I'm trying to publish is to an Azure Function App.

The piece I'm lost on is where to get the "accessToken" for authenticating the Function App.

I've tried to do this via the Function App > Authentication / Authorisation section with no luck.

I've also tried to do this via App Registrations > Certificates and Secrets.

I'm a) not sure which process to follow and b) which information to copy for the Access Token.

I can't seem find any step-by-step instructions anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this access token by opening a terminal and logging into the azure portal:

```
az login
```

And then:

```
    az account get-access-token
```